# How to Auto-Upload Mails in Local Folders to Gmail Folders in Thunderbird?

Tags: email, sync, thunderbird, gmail, imap

I have an account in Thunderbird that is connected to Gmail for Work through IMAP(OAuth2). I was trying to migrate 25,000+ emails from local hard disk to **Local folders**. Then from local folders I selected all the mails and clicked on **Move To** >> [Gmail] >> All Mail.

However, once the internet connection dropped, it didn't resume the upload automatically also inside Thunderbird All Mail shows 13000 mails but online inside gmail All Mail shows 6500 only.

When will the rest get synced?

Also, now that the upload has stopped Thunderbird is again downloading the All Mail data in Thunderbird which is absurd.